# Find -prune argument order affects output list

Tags: bash, find

I have the following directory structure (minimal example):

```
testdir
testdir/test2
testdir/test2/test2a
testdir/test2/test2a/test2aa
testdir/test1
testdir/test1/test1a
testdir/test1/test1a/test1aa
testdir/test1/test1b
testdir/test1/test1b/test1ba
```

I would like to find only folders in the depth layer directly below `testdir`, excluding a certain folder name, here `test1`. First, the output without excluding `test1`:

```
user@xyz:/home/user $ find testdir/* -type d -prune
testdir/test1
testdir/test2
```

Now, I can exclude `test1`:

```
user@xyz:/home/user $ find testdir/* -type d -prune ! -name test1
testdir/test2
```

However, by changing the order of the `-prune` argument, subdirectories of `test1` are returned:

```
user@xyz:/home/user $ find testdir/* -type d ! -name test1 -prune
testdir/test1/test1a
testdir/test1/test1b
testdir/test2
```

Why does the last command return the subdirectories `test1a` and `test1b`? I thought the order of the options would not matter, but apparently it does. As far as I understand (not sure about it), `-prune` prevents `find` from returning any paths below the patterns matched according to the `find` options set. But the only match in the first layer below `testdir` should be `test2`. Could somebody clarify this for me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Find -prune argument order affects output list

That's not especially surprising just on the face of it.  The behavior of `find` is sensitive in general to the relative order of predicates and actions.

The POSIX specifications for `find`'s behavior are a bit unspecific, but I think GNU `find`'s behavior is pretty typical in the relevant regards, even if that's not actually the `find` you are using.  [Its manual page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) says:

> GNU `find` searches the directory tree rooted at each given
> starting-point by evaluating the given expression **from left to right**
> [...] **until
> the outcome is known** (the left hand side is false for *and* operations,
> true for *or*), at which point `find` moves on to the next file name.

(emphasis added).

Thus, if you put the `-name` predicate *before* the `-prune` action then the `-prune` is performed only for paths that pass the `-name` test, but if you put the `-name` predicate *after* the `-prune` then the `-name` affects only whether paths are printed, not whether they are pruned.

Comment: Note also: if you do not explicitly specify a logical operator with which to combine the results of predicates and actions then the default is *and*, which is usually what you want.  This answer assumes that is already well understood.

Comment: Alright. I did not know that -name affects which paths are pruned, I thought it always determines only which paths are printed/returned. Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: @bproxauf, it's not that `-name` *in particular* affects which paths are pruned.  It's that *every* predicate that comes before `-prune` on the command line affects whether the `-prune` is evaluated at all.  If it is not evaluated, it has no effect.

Comment: Ok, so with `find testdir/* -type d ! -name test1 -prune`, `-prune` is evaluated for all directories not called `test1`. But then, omitting the name test, i.e. `find testdir/* -type d -prune`, why does it not give `testdir/test1/test1a` or `testdir/test1/test1b`. What about the name check leads it to give those two additional directories?

Comment: Does it first go one layer deep, prune any directories not called `test` (and stop descending for those directories), i.e. `test2`, and for the directory called `test` descend one layer deeper where then the name test passes and its subdirectories `test1a` and `test1b` are pruned (and the further descent to `test1aa` and `test1ba` is stopped)?

Comment: @bproxauf, with `find testdir/* -type d -prune`, `find` prunes *every* directory it processes, so it never descends into `testdir/test1`, and thus never even considers `testdir/test1/test1a` *etc*..  That's the meaning and purpose of `-prune`, and the effect is equivalent to that of `find testdir/* -maxdepth 0 -type d`.